# passport-facebook node app doesn't seen to work

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport-facebook, passport.js

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpanorart-victor3991.c9users.io%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=emails&client_id=547453695448009

My app is still under development.
It used to work with facebook login. But it suddenly got to the 500 error with the text: 
Sorry, something went wrong.

We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

I thought this might be the facebook internal network error but the issue had been on for almost a month.

Does anyone have some idea why it's happening?
I'm also using google oauth with similar logic and it's working fine.

Comment: `emails` is not a valid permission.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me it was the scope passed via passport that was incorrect. I used the google scope which was profile and email, whereas facebook required `publish_actions`. Hope this helps

Comment: To add on this point, if you only require user basic information, don't pass any scope, just use `passport.authenticate('facebook')`